# Obtener resultado de Axios resp.data

Tags: javascript, json, axios

Estoy realizando una consulta y me devuelve todo el valor de la página pero quiero solo sacar un solo fragmento y no sé como puedo hacerlo si me pudieseis echar un cable.

El código es:

```js
axios({
  method: 'get',
  url: 'https://...',
  headers: {
    'Autent': 'kzbia9ucml4ho'
  }
})
  .then(resp => {
    console.log(resp.data);
});
```

Y me devuelve esta respuesta.

```js
{
  data: [
    {
      id: '25',
      login: 'Login',
      name: 'Nombre',
      type: '',
      status_type: '2',
      description: '',
      image_url: 'example.png',
      offline_url: 'example.png',
      count: 23
    }
  ]
}
```

He intentado de diferentes formas, pero solo recibo undefined.

```js
  .then(resp => {
    console.log(resp.data.id);
});
```

Cómo puedo hacerlo, estoy un poco verde en esto y no encuentro mucha información al respecto.

---

Haciendo la prueba tal y como me comenta el compañero, recibo el error UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

Haciendo catch me devuelve esto,

```js
{
  status: 200,
  statusText: 'OK',
  headers: {
    'access-control-allow-origin': '*',
    'cache-control': 'no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, private',
    'content-type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    expires: '0',
    pragma: 'no-cache',
    'ratelimit-limit': '30',
    'ratelimit-remaining': '29',
    'ratelimit-reset': '1585434263',
    server: 'envoy',
    'timing-allow-origin': 'https://...',
    'trace-id': 'b2c32f0399bccfssfdda8d6da7f0f87',
    'x-ctxlog-logid': '1-5e7fce95-eeefd54e0c156c99c7ed89f',
    'content-length': '413',
    date: 'Sat, 28 Mar 2020 22:24:21 GMT',
    connection: 'close',
    'x-served-by': 'cache-sea4451-SEA, cache-dca17765-DCA',
    'x-cache': 'MISS, MISS',
    'x-cache-hits': '0, 0',
    'x-timer': 'S1585434261.152578,VS0,VS0,VE90',
    vary: 'Accept-Encoding',
    'strict-transport-security': 'max-age=300'
  },
  config: {
    url: 'https:...',
    method: 'get',
    headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
      'Autent': 'kzbia9ucml4ho',
      'User-Agent': 'axios/0.19.2'
    },
    transformRequest: [ [Function: transformRequest] ],
    transformResponse: [ [Function: transformResponse] ],
    timeout: 0,
    adapter: [Function: httpAdapter],
    xsrfCookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
    xsrfHeaderName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN',
    maxContentLength: -1,
    validateStatus: [Function: validateStatus],
    data: undefined
  },
  request: ClientRequest {
    _events: [Object: null prototype] {
      socket: [Function],
      abort: [Function],
      aborted: [Function],
      error: [Function],
      timeout: [Function],
      prefinish: [Function: requestOnPrefinish]
    },
    _eventsCount: 6,
    _maxListeners: undefined,
    outputData: [],
    outputSize: 0,
    writable: true,
    _last: true,
    chunkedEncoding: false,
    shouldKeepAlive: false,
    useChunkedEncodingByDefault: false,
    sendDate: false,
    _removedConnection: false,
    _removedContLen: false,
    _removedTE: false,
    _contentLength: 0,
    _hasBody: true,
    _trailer: '',
    finished: true,
    _headerSent: true,
    socket: TLSSocket {
      _tlsOptions: [Object],
      _secureEstablished: true,
      _securePending: false,
      _newSessionPending: false,
      _controlReleased: true,
      _SNICallback: null,
      servername: '.net',
      alpnProtocol: false,
      authorized: true,
      authorizationError: null,
      encrypted: true,
      _events: [Object],
      _eventsCount: 9,
      connecting: false,
      _hadError: false,
      _parent: null,
      _host: '.net',
      _readableState: [ReadableState],
      readable: true,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      _writableState: [WritableState],
      writable: false,
      allowHalfOpen: false,
      _sockname: null,
      _pendingData: null,
      _pendingEncoding: '',
      server: undefined,
      _server: null,
      ssl: [TLSWrap],
      _requestCert: true,
      _rejectUnauthorized: true,
      parser: null,
      _httpMessage: [Circular],
      [Symbol(res)]: [TLSWrap],
      [Symbol(asyncId)]: 8,
      [Symbol(kHandle)]: [TLSWrap],
      [Symbol(lastWriteQueueSize)]: 0,
      [Symbol(timeout)]: null,
      [Symbol(kBytesRead)]: 0,
      [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 0,
      [Symbol(connect-options)]: [Object]
    },
    connection: TLSSocket {
      _tlsOptions: [Object],
      _secureEstablished: true,
      _securePending: false,
      _newSessionPending: false,
      _controlReleased: true,
      _SNICallback: null,
      servername: '.net',
      alpnProtocol: false,
      authorized: true,
      authorizationError: null,
      encrypted: true,
      _events: [Object],
      _eventsCount: 9,
      connecting: false,
      _hadError: false,
      _parent: null,
      _host: '.net',
      _readableState: [ReadableState],
      readable: true,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      _writableState: [WritableState],
      writable: false,
      allowHalfOpen: false,
      _sockname: null,
      _pendingData: null,
      _pendingEncoding: '',
      server: undefined,
      _server: null,
      ssl: [TLSWrap],
      _requestCert: true,
      _rejectUnauthorized: true,
      parser: null,
      _httpMessage: [Circular],
      [Symbol(res)]: [TLSWrap],
      [Symbol(asyncId)]: 8,
      [Symbol(kHandle)]: [TLSWrap],
      [Symbol(lastWriteQueueSize)]: 0,
      [Symbol(timeout)]: null,
      [Symbol(kBytesRead)]: 0,
      [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 0,
      [Symbol(connect-options)]: [Object]
    },
    _header: 'GET /page/users?login=login HTTP/1.1\r' +
      '\nAccept: application/json, text/plain, */*\r' +
      '\nAutent: kzbia9ucml4ho\r' +
      '\nUser-Agent: axios/0.19.2\r' +
      '\nHost: xxx.net\r' +
      '\nConnection: close\r' +
      '\n\r' +
      '\n',
    _onPendingData: [Function: noopPendingOutput],
    agent: Agent {
      _events: [Object],
      _eventsCount: 1,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      defaultPort: 443,
      protocol: 'https:',
      options: [Object],
      requests: {},
      sockets: [Object],
      freeSockets: {},
      keepAliveMsecs: 1000,
      keepAlive: false,
      maxSockets: Infinity,
      maxFreeSockets: 256,
      maxCachedSessions: 100,
      _sessionCache: [Object]
    },
    socketPath: undefined,
    method: 'GET',
    path: '/page/users?login=login',
    _ended: true,
    res: IncomingMessage {
      _readableState: [ReadableState],
      readable: false,
      _events: [Object],
      _eventsCount: 3,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      socket: [TLSSocket],
      connection: [TLSSocket],
      httpVersionMajor: 1,
      httpVersionMinor: 1,
      httpVersion: '1.1',
      complete: true,
      headers: [Object],
      rawHeaders: [Array],
      trailers: {},
      rawTrailers: [],
      aborted: false,
      upgrade: false,
      url: '',
      method: null,
      statusCode: 200,
      statusMessage: 'OK',
      client: [TLSSocket],
      _consuming: false,
      _dumped: false,
      req: [Circular],
      responseUrl: 'https://...',
      redirects: []
    },
    aborted: false,
    timeoutCb: null,
    upgradeOrConnect: false,
    parser: null,
    maxHeadersCount: null,
    _redirectable: Writable {
      _writableState: [WritableState],
      writable: true,
      _events: [Object],
      _eventsCount: 2,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      _options: [Object],
      _redirectCount: 0,
      _redirects: [],
      _requestBodyLength: 0,
      _requestBodyBuffers: [],
      _onNativeResponse: [Function],
      _currentRequest: [Circular],
      _currentUrl: 'https://...'
    },
    [Symbol(isCorked)]: false,
    [Symbol(outHeadersKey)]: [Object: null prototype] {
      accept: [Array],
      'Autent': [Array],
      'user-agent': [Array],
      host: [Array]
    }
  },
  data: { data: [ [Object] ] }
}
```

Comment: para acceder los datos tienes que hacerlo así `resp.data.data[0]`

Comment: Así me devuelve todo nuevamente como si se tratase solo de resp.data

Comment: @ajuni880ahora solucionado, ahora si me deja hacer resp.data.data[0].id una pregunta como supiste que necesitaba otro data para leerlo.

Comment: @ajuni880es por la terminación de data: { data: [ [Object] ] } ahora creo que lo entiendo, muchísimas gracias enserio.

Comment: tienes que ver lo que es`resp.data` es un objeto que tiene otro `data` dentro es el array. Deberías leer sobre objetos en javascript

Comment: @ajuni880 si aún estoy muy verde en eso procuro leer al máximo pero poco a poco voy haciendo.

Answer (score 1):

`data` es un array tienes que usar indice para acceder al primer elemento

```
{
  data: [
    {
      id: '25',
      login: 'Login',
      name: 'Nombre',
      type: '',
      status_type: '2',
      description: '',
      image_url: 'example.png',
      offline_url: 'example.png',
      count: 23
    }
  ]
}
console.log(resp.data.data[0].id)
```

Comment: Si eso también lo comprobé e incluso llamar solo al array, pero me devuelve error (node:17507) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined y sin .id es undefined.

Comment: este `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning` error indica que falla la request y no debería entrar en el `then` puedes añadir un `catch` y mirar porque falla. Sin mas código no puedo ayudar mucho

Comment: Si falla porque se ve que no es la forma correcta, ya que sin poner el array funciona y carga la información que proporciono arriba, es básicamente una url autentificada  que me genera el array que ves arriba pero no me deja extraer solo uno extraigo todo.

Comment: puedes actualizar tu pregunta y poner el error que te da en el `catch` y no entiendo esta parte "pero no me deja extraer solo uno extraigo todo"

Comment: Perdón por no ser especifico, si utilizo console.log(resp.data); me da todo el array como se puede ver arriba pero cuando introduzco el valor que me mencionaste es cuando desencadena dicho error. Cómo puedo hacer el catch estuve viendo y no me oriento mucho.

Comment: aqui tienes un ejemplo https://github.com/axios/axios#handling-errors

Comment: Si, estuve viendo eso pero no se implementarlo el catch de la manera correcta estoy muy verde,  he actualizado el tema y he puesto el ejemplo con el array que me dijiste donde se aprecia el mismo error.

Comment: pero eso no es correcto.  Tienes que entender que `example` es un objeto que tiene una propiedad que es `data` que es la que tiene el array de datos. Tienes que poner esto `example.data[0].id`. El `catch` lo añades asi `axios(...).then(resp => { console.log(res)}).catch(err => { console.log(err)})`

Comment: Si perdón lo había puesto mal, ahí he editado y he pegado el catch que devuelve.